# How to Refresh A named divison and not the entire page?

Tags: jquery, iframe, refresh

I just can't seem to get this right. Someone who helped me before told me to use jQuery and I have tried and just cannot get it to work. I am trying to automatically refresh a division on my html page I made and not the entire page.

I tried the meta refresh but that does the entre page. Everywhere I search has similar answer but I cannot get it to work. the division I am trying to refresh is called "Frame" I just need it to refresh every 45 minutes.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Station 47</title>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="DarkRed">
        <body a link="black" vlink="black">
        <center><font face="Times New Roman" size="6"><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">Naval District Washington Fire Department Station 47</marquee>
    </body>

    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p align="left">
                <iframe id="Iframe1" src="https://webview.active911.com/client/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="2360" height="930"></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <iframe id="Iframe2" src="http://www.chart.state.md.us/video/video.php?feed=7401e25800f700d700437a45351f0214" width="400" height="400" Frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                    <iframe id="Iframe3" src="http://www.chart.state.md.us/video/video.php?feed=7e01ec5800f700d700437a45351f0214" width="400" height="400" Frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                    <iframe id="Iframe4" src="http://www.chart.state.md.us/video/video.php?feed=7901e75800f700d700437a45351f0214" width="400" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                    <iframe id="Iframe5" src="http://www.chart.state.md.us/video/video.php?feed=6100bdd12e83001c00503336c4235c0a" width="400" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                    <iframe id="Iframe6" src="http://www.chart.state.md.us/video/video.php?feed=4900c5b02e84001c00503336c4235c0a" width="400" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe> 
                    <iframe id="Iframe7" src="http://api.wunderground.com/api/5ce4445b4bd79f9a/animatedradar/q/MD/Annapolis.gif?&width=415&height=415&newmaps=1&timelabel=1&timelabel.y=10&num=15&delay=50" width="338" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></td>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

Comment: first, please fix your html ... Then, I don't see any JS in your snippet. What did you try ?

Comment: I did fix it a second ago with your correction thank you. I did not put the js in there, I am confused because a lot of answers I found referenced PHP files. I am new to this and it is a complete miracle that I got this far. In your opinion what is the simplest way to do what I am trying

Comment: I tried the Meta refresh before but it reloads the whole page. JS is confusing and I cant figure out how to relate it to refreshing the Src's. The Src's I have are traffic cameras and a weather radar. The first frame active 911 it cant reload over and over. This page is for our firehouse alerting system

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are asking. Do you want to reload all the iframes ?  Your HTML code has still about 33 Errors... You can use https://validator.w3.org to help you find them.

Comment: yes I want to refresh Iframe 2,3,4,5,6,7 every 45 minutes and that is it. Thank you for the link I will use it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your html code is correct, here is what you can do:

1. include jquery (add the following in your head or at the bottom of your page, just before the body closing tag):

   ```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. using jQuery, write a function able to get all the iframes:

   ```
   function reloadFrames(){
      $(".Frames iframe").each(function(i, iframe){
         iframe.contentDocument.location.reload(true);
      });
   }
   ```
3. call the function every 45 minutes. For that, you can use `setInterval`. The first parameter is the function to call, the second one is the frequency, in ms:

   ```
   setInterval(reloadFrames, 45*60*1000);
   ```

So to recap, you can paste the following at the end of your body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

      setInterval(reloadFrames, 1000);

      function reloadFrames() {
        console.log("reloading iframes")
        $(".Frames iframe").each(function(i, iframe) {
          iframe.contentDocument.location.reload(true);
        });
      }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Under the setInterval(reloadFrames, 45*60*1000), I understand that it is in milliseconds. What does the 45*60*1000 do?

Comment: I understand it now 45X60=2,700  2700 x 1000 =2700000 milliseconds

Comment: @ Derlin I have it all in there and it is still not working I set the interval to 5000 for 5 seconds just to see if it works.